# Netbeans 8 is doing crazy auto horizontal scroll

Tags: netbeans, ide, netbeans-8

Netbeans 8 is doing crazy auto horizontal scroll, how to disable this!
When coding a long lines, netbeans automatically move horizontally and focus to your mouse pointer.

```
To replicate :
1. Do a long code, make sure you will have horizontal scroll visible.Sample :
<label class="labelContent"><input type="text" id="holDate" name="holDate" required value="<?php echo ($update["data"]["date"] ? $update["data"]["date"] : ""); ?>" /></label>
2. Edit above code type="text" to hidden, you will notice that the netbeans will move your view automatically and focus to the mouse cursor!

Note : Even using "Line Wrap" to anywhere, you will see this movement! this make my head break, probably same with you!!? LOL hope someone knows how to disable this.
```

Comment: I also noticed another problem when trying to drag&drop a text fragment - netbeans starts scrolling so fast, that it's impossible to drop the text where you want it.

Answer (score -2):

SOLVED * PROBLEM: In NetBeans> Tools> Options> Editor> tab "Folding"> "Language: All languages," Disable * Enable Code Folding option

Comment: Translation:
* PROBLEM SOLVED: In NetBeans> Tools> Options> Editor> tab "Double"> "Language: All languages," Disable the option * Enable Code Folding.

Comment: Or: SOLVED * PROBLEM: In NetBeans> Tools> Options> Editor> tab "Folding"> "Language: All languages," Disable * Enable Code Folding option